# Requests to Foursquare API is producing no output when called from the terminal

Tags: python, api, foursquare

The following code doesn't produce any output when I run `python findArestaurant.py` in the terminal

It's supposed to produce an output that lists restaurants in places around the world.

I signed up for a Foursqure dev account, created an app, and was then able to copy both the client id, and client secret. However, no output?

filename: findArestaurant.py

```
from geocode import getGeocodeLocation
import json
import httplib2

import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

foursquare_client_id = "entered_here"
foursquare_client_secret = "entered_here"


def findARestaurant(mealType,location):
    #1. Use getGeocodeLocation to get the latitude and longitude coordinates of the location string.
    latitude, longitude = getGeocodeLocation(location)
    #2.  Use foursquare API to find a nearby restaurant with the latitude, longitude, and mealType strings.
    #HINT: format for url will be something like https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi
    url = ('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&v=20130815&ll=%s,%s&query=%s' % (foursquare_client_id, foursquare_client_secret,latitude,longitude,mealType))
    h = httplib2.Http()
    result = json.loads(h.request(url,'GET')[1])

    if result['response']['venues']:
        #3.  Grab the first restaurant
        restaurant = result['response']['venues'][0]
        venue_id = restaurant['id'] 
        restaurant_name = restaurant['name']
        restaurant_address = restaurant['location']['formattedAddress']
        address = ""
        for i in restaurant_address:
            address += i + " "
        restaurant_address = address
        #4.  Get a  300x300 picture of the restaurant using the venue_id (you can change this by altering the 300x300 value in the URL or replacing it with 'orginal' to get the original picture
        url = ('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/%s/photos?client_id=%s&v=20150603&client_secret=%s' % ((venue_id,foursquare_client_id,foursquare_client_secret)))
        result = json.loads(h.request(url, 'GET')[1])
        #5.  Grab the first image
        if result['response']['photos']['items']:
            firstpic = result['response']['photos']['items'][0]
            prefix = firstpic['prefix']
            suffix = firstpic['suffix']
            imageURL = prefix + "300x300" + suffix
        else:
            #6.  if no image available, insert default image url
            imageURL = "http://pixabay.com/get/8926af5eb597ca51ca4c/1433440765/cheeseburger-34314_1280.png?direct"
        #7.  return a dictionary containing the restaurant name, address, and image url
        restaurantInfo = {'name':restaurant_name, 'address':restaurant_address, 'image':imageURL} 
        print ("Restaurant Name: %s" % restaurantInfo['name'] )
        print ("Restaurant Address: %s" % restaurantInfo['address'] )
        print ("Image: %s \n" % restaurantInfo['image'] )
        return restaurantInfo
    else:
        print ( "No Restaurants Found for %s" % location )
        return "No Restaurants Found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    findARestaurant("Pizza", "Tokyo, Japan")
    findARestaurant("Tacos", "Jakarta, Indonesia")
    findARestaurant("Tapas", "Maputo, Mozambique")
    findARestaurant("Falafel", "Cairo, Egypt")
    findARestaurant("Spaghetti", "New Delhi, India")
    findARestaurant("Cappuccino", "Geneva, Switzerland")
    findARestaurant("Sushi", "Los Angeles, California")
    findARestaurant("Steak", "La Paz, Bolivia")
    findARestaurant("Gyros", "Sydney, Australia")
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.